# Events from UserControl in Gridview are not being fired

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a gridview that has a usercontrol in a template column on each row.

During the RowDataBound event I subscribe to the event as follows

```
DateTimePicker dtp = (DateTimePicker)e.Row.FindControl("DateTimePickerPromoRunDate");
dtp.OnDateChanged +=new CustomEventHandler(dtp_OnDateChanged);
```

And then in the control I have the following

```
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public CustomEventArgs(DateTime dateSelected)
    {
        DateSelected = dateSelected;
    }
    public DateTime DateSelected { get; set; }
}

public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs e);

public partial class DateTimePicker : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event CustomEventHandler OnDateChanged;
    protected virtual void OnCustomEvent(CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DateSelected = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxDate.Text);
        if (OnDateChanged != null)
            OnDateChanged(this, e);
    }
 [blah blah blah]
 OnCustomEvent(new CustomEventArgs(Calendar1.SelectedDate));
```

The problem is that when I call the OnCustomEvent method the OnDateChanged event is null as if I haven't subscribed to it.

A similar problem exists where if I set the properties of the usercontrol on databound when I attempt to use it those properties are null... can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around my problem by simply putting the event call in the metadata side of the page. It's not ideal but it's firing now

Comment: can u explain more and write that code for me plz , i am in a troublee :$

Comment: tanx , i founded this yesterday :(

Answer (score 0):

You may have to subscribe your ondatechanged on each post back. otherwise the page doesn't remember it.

Comment: It is I think since the subscribe is on the RowDataBound?

Comment: may be the RowDataBound is not fired on each postback.

Comment: It is being fired on each post back.

I changed the code around a bit so now I only subscribe to the user control event when a checkbox in the grid is clicked but still it loses the subscription